# Checkboxes with FormData.Append

Tags: php, ajax, form-data

I am using Javascript FormData.Append to pass values to a php file, but I cannot get check boxes working.  For Example

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="XXX" value="XXX" /><label>XXX Option</label>
```

JS

```
FormData.append( 'XXX', $('input[name=XXX]').val());
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['XXX'])) {    echo "checked!";}
```

Whether I check the box or not, I get the response - checked!

OR PHP

```
$XXX= $_POST['XXX'];
```

The var $XXX shows value XXX whether checked or not.

How can I pass checkboxes using this method so I can differentiate if the checkbox is ticked or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

`document.getElementsByName('XXX')[0].checked`

To check the status of whether it's checked or not.

Comment: Yes that works false/true but when it passes the FormData I think it passes the value, whether or not it is checked.  How do I pass a checked value through JS to PHP

Comment: if(document.getElementsByName('XXX')[0].checked){m_data.append( 'XXX', $('input[name=XXX]').val());}  works in the JS.  There is probably a better way but works...